# Depth to world registration hololens2 unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, computer-vision, hololens, mrtk, projective-geometry

I'm working on a program on hololens2 research mode on unity. Hololens give us a depth image that is distance from depth sensor to object in front, for every pixel.

What I do is for every pixel I project pixel to image plane, then backproject it according to depth distance captured by depth sensor and it gives me the xyz in depth sensor coordinate frame. now it is needed to transform this coordinate to global coordinate system. to do so I get camera coordinate from unity by `cam_pose = Camera.main.transform` and in the other hand saved depth sensor extrinsic matrix.

From these two matrices I create a `depth_to_world = cam_pose @ inv(extrinsic)`. Now for every xyz on depth I perform `global_xyz = depth_to_world @ xyz` to get point in real world. Problem is it return a point with 10-15 cm error. What am I doing wrong? (code is in python)

```
    x = self.us[Depth_i, Depth_j] # projection from pixels to image plane
    y = self.vs[Depth_i, Depth_j] # projection from pixels to image plane
    D = distance_img[Depth_i, Depth_j] #distance_img is depth image
    distance = 1000*float(D) / np.sqrt(x * x + y * y + 1) #distance according to spherical image plane D is in millimeter
    depth_to_world = cam_pose @ np.linalg.inv(Constants.camera_extrinsic)
    X = (np.array([x * distance, y * distance, 1.0 * distance, 1])).reshape(4, 1)
    point = (depth_to_world @ X )[0:3, 0]
```

Comment: Would you share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The initial position of Camera.main is Vector3.zero (according to https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/1a73ff73a1a56f0cdbd4d222c92f3cdbb95d6eae/Assets/MRTK/Services/CameraSystem/MixedRealityCameraSystem.cs#L153), and it is supposed to be the center of the headset. However, the raw data returned from depth camera should be the actual distance to the physical postion of depth camera(it is placed in the front of Hololens 2 headset). Would you set an offset and test it again?

Comment: I tried to present code clear, sorry if there is unclearity. If there is somewhere unclear, please ask. I tried the offset it didn't work. I used the offset to be subtracted from D. `D = D - offset`. btw shoudn't camera extrinsic fix this problem? we expect depth camera extrinsic to be transformation from depth sensor coordinate to hololens coordinate witch is considered.

Comment: when I used offset, It seemed to move point toward hololens (on my head). did't fix shift of points. and it's reasonable somehow I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it! according to (https://github.com/petergu684/HoloLens2-ResearchMode-Unity) first I passed unity world origin to a winrt plugin, and depth_to_world was depth_to_world = inv(extrinsic) * cam_pose witch cam_pose is given by TryLocateAtTimeStamp. And other point is that unity coordinate is left handed (surprisingly!) so we should multiply a (-1) to z. (z <- -z)
my depth_to_world transformation was near but not correct.